# How can i save record in List type with spring in mongo database?

Tags: java, arrays, spring, mongodb, algorithm

In the main method, a single long URL and number will be entered from the screen, and unique short URLs will be generated as much as the number of pieces.

This is how the table and method work. But my need has changed and I can't revise my code. While filling the table, only one String type long url will come, but shortUrl information will come in List type. How can I save this to the table?

```
|      longUrl     |    shortUrl      | campaingName |   
|  ----------------| -----------------| -------------|
|  "www.nike.com"  | "qwerty.co/xyz1" |   NIKE10     | 
|  "www.nike.com"  | "qwerty.co/hjx9" |   NIKE10     |
|  "www.chef.com"  | "qwerty.co/v3y7" |   CHEF12     |
|  "www.nike.com"  | "qwery.co/rto57" |   NIKE99     |
```

I have a table like this. I use the following method to save data to the table.

```
public BaseResponse insertRecord(UrlsInfoCreateRequest urlsInfoCreateRequest) {

        log.info("insertRecord is started..");

        BaseResponse response = new BaseResponse();
        UrlsInfo urlsInfo = new UrlsInfo();
        urlsInfo.setLongUrl(urlsInfoCreateRequest.getLongUrl());
        urlsInfo.setShortUrl(urlsInfoCreateRequest.getShortUrl());
        urlsInfo.setCampaignName(urlsInfoCreateRequest.getCampaignName());
        urlsInfo.setCreateDate(new Date());
        UrlsInfo urlsInfo1 = this.urlInfoRepository.save(urlsInfo);

        if (urlsInfo1 == null){
            log.error("Record can not insert in the table.");
            throw new MongoException("Could not save to database!");
        }

        return BaseResponse.success("SUCCESS");
    }
```

My Request Information :

```
@Data
public class UrlsInfoCreateRequest {

    private String longUrl;
    private String shortUrl;
    private String campaignName;

}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@Document(collection = "campaign_url_table")
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class UrlsInfo extends BaseModel {

    @Field("longUrl")
    @JsonProperty("longUrl")
    private String longUrl;

    @Field("shortUrl")
    @JsonProperty("shortUrl")
    private String shortUrl;

    @Field("campaignName")
    @JsonProperty("campaignName")
    private String campaignName;

}
```

Can you help me how to edit my insert method so that the shortUrl information is a List?

campaignName will be unique, so 2 short urls were generated for the NIKE10 campaign.

Comment: Why can't you revise your code?

Comment: I can't find how to fix

Comment: You can update your `shortUrl` variable type to `List<String>` instead of `String` and pass it accordingly